# What is the default font for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

When using ggplot2 in R, it clearly has a `base_family` font. What is it? as the documentation just uses "" as can be seen in...

```
?theme_light()
```

It looks like ArialMT but not sure...

Comment: Hmmwhat does `windowsFonts()` say? It should contain the default mappings.

Comment: Working on a mac, so that isn't available at the moment...

Comment: Themes are complicated. http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/themes.html

Comment: `windowsFonts()` gives you the mapping to the installed system fonts, but it is not clear to me which one it picks when the specified theme family is empty (`""`)

Comment: You can set the theme for a session with `theme_set()` it could go into your `.Rprofile` for example.

Comment: It is definitely "sans", and then what ever that is mapped to. You use `windowsFont()` to find that on Windows.

Comment: Looks like [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Fonts/) shows some layer text defaults, including that the default of `""` is sans.

Answer (score 41):

This is not a complete answer, but some of the pieces are as follows:

- Themes are complicated:  http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html
- `theme_set()` and `theme_get()` can set and query your default theme for the session
- A theme is a list, and the named `text` list and its `family` element will tell you want font name is being used. You can set that in the theme call in a ggplot to override the default for that theme.
- In windows the `windowsFonts()` will tell you the mapping between font names and your installed system font names. I have no idea how to do this in the OS X or Linux platforms though.
- The default ones seem to be `serif`, `sans`, and `mono` across all platforms.

My main open question is what does the blank family name "" map to, since that is usually what is in the themes. If nothing is specified the default somehow gets set to `sans`, since that it what it seems to be.

I also couldn't figure out how to replace the default font family in `theme_gray()`. Think it is time for a question...

```
> theme_get()$text
List of 10
 $ family    : chr ""
 $ face      : chr "plain"
 $ colour    : chr "black"
 $ size      : num 11
 $ hjust     : num 0.5
 $ vjust     : num 0.5
 $ angle     : num 0
 $ lineheight: num 0.9
 $ margin    :Classes 'margin', 'unit'  atomic [1:4] 0 0 0 0
  .. ..- attr(*, "unit")= chr "pt"
  .. ..- attr(*, "valid.unit")= int 8
 $ debug     : logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "element_text" "element"
```

And the system font mapping in windows:

```
> windowsFonts()
$serif
[1] "TT Times New Roman"

$sans
[1] "TT Arial"

$mono
[1] "TT Courier New"

>
```

An example:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars") +
  xlab("Weight (x1000 lb)") + ylab("Miles per Gallon") +
  theme(text=element_text(size=16,  family="serif"))
```

[image]

Comment: I think you can change the default font like this: `theme_set(theme_get() + theme(text = element_text(family = 'Open Sans')))`

Comment: The link at the beginning of the answer is broken

Comment: Oh, thanks for that. Now if I could only remember what it was :)

Comment: The equivalent to `windowsFonts()` in Linux is `X11Fonts()`.

Answer (score 10):

If you export a figure created using ggplot2 (using RStudio: Export -> Copy to Clipboard) and load it into a graphics editor you can select and edit each individual aspect of the figure, including text.

Using Inkscape, the default font for all my ggplot2 plots is Arial.

Comment: I think it is actually "sans" which defaults to Arial on many systems, but this really depends on the operating system and settings, on Linux ggplot will retrieve the default sans from fontconfig I guess (which will return Bitstream Vera Sans or Deja Vu Sans on a typical Linux system).

Comment: Another option is to `ggsave` as `svg`, and load in a text editor.  Search for a `<text` element's `font-family` value