# Is there a list of common names of font families for use in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I just need a list of names of font families for use in ggplot. I know this varies with operative systems and installs, but there are some commonalities and I'm just looking for a handy reference list of what the most common names of font families are. Like
* Times / Times New Roman
* Comic Sans MS

etc.

I've googled but since fonts are machine specific I can't find any handy list of that kind.

Literally just any list of common font family names to expect would be good. It doesn't need to be exclusively tailored to my machine.

No extra package installs wanted, please.

Comment: Related: [What is the default font for ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610165/what-is-the-default-font-for-ggplot2)

Comment: If you don't want extra packages, you don't have a lot of control. You can ask for `serif`, `sans`, and `mono` but exactly what those map to on each OS/machine might not be the same. Historically fonts across operating systems weren't that easy to match up and since R has been around a long time, it has a more hands off approach to such things in the core libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use anything that comes back when you run this from line of code from the `fontExtra` package. It will list all fonts available on your machine `extrafont::fonts()`

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of ways to get the list of fonts. `quartzFonts()` or `windowsFonts()` list default mappings for three device-independent font family names: "sans" for a sans-serif font, "serif" for a serif font and "mono" for a monospaced font.

```
> quartzFonts()
$serif
[1] "Times-Roman"      "Times-Bold"       "Times-Italic"     "Times-BoldItalic"

$sans
[1] "Helvetica"             "Helvetica-Bold"        "Helvetica-Oblique"    
[4] "Helvetica-BoldOblique"

$mono
[1] "Courier"             "Courier-Bold"        "Courier-Oblique"    
[4] "Courier-BoldOblique"
```

This is usually not a complete list of available fonts. The following code gives a more complete list:

```
install.packages("extrafont")
library(extrafont)

font_import() # Import fonts that are available on the system, this step may take some time
fonts() # list fonts
# fonttable() # the table provides a bit more information

head(fonts(), 10)
 [1] "aakar"           "Abyssinica SIL"  "Ani"             "AnjaliOldLipi"  
 [5] "Arimo"           "Caladea"         "Carlito"         "Chandas"        
 [9] "Comfortaa"       "Comfortaa Light"
```

However, the fonts on the chart may not look as you expect. To test them, you can use the following code:

```
# Select the fonts you want to test
font.name = c("Ani",
          "Comic Sans MS",
          "Courier",
          "Kinnari",
          "Noto Sans",
          "Open Sans",
          "Roboto Condensed",
          "Saab",
          "Samanata",
          "Times",
          "Times-Roman",
          "Ubuntu Condensed")

font.table = data.frame(font.name = font.name, pos = 1:length(font.name))
p = ggplot(font.table, aes( x= "font.name", y = pos)) + 
    geom_text(aes(label=font.name, family = font.name), size = 10) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
          panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
ggsave("font_examples.png")
```

[image]

Note that the "Times-Roman" does not look as expected.

In addition, you can play with bold, italic, and bold italic variants of the fonts. See the following [link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Fonts/) for details.