# What is the default font in R

Tags: r

On https://rdrr.io/snippets/ I ran the following code:

```
par(family = "xxxxxxx")

  plot(x         =  1:50,
       y         = (1:50)^2,
       xlab      = "X axis title",
       ylab      = "Y axis title",
       cex.axis  = 1.4,
       cex.main  = 2,
       cex.lab   = 1.5) 

  mtext(side=3, line=2, adj=0.5, cex=2, font=2.1, "Main title")
```

Running this code in RStudio (running in Linux Ubuntu 20.04) gives the same plot with the same font.

So it looks if 'family' is assigned a non-existing font, R chooses something itself.
What exactly is the name of the font that is chosen by R?

Comment: Related: [What is the default font for ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610165/what-is-the-default-font-for-ggplot2)

Comment: Quoting `?par`: _"The default value is "" which means that the default device fonts will be used (and what those are should be listed on the help page for the device). "_